# Generating Grayscale Values Of An Image

Tags: r, image, image-recognition, mnist

I have trained a model (on the famous MNIST data) to learn to identify images of digits from 0 to 9. The intensity values were provided as feature sets.

Now I want to test the model myself, for that I want to say write a number on MS Paint and run through the model.

I know how to use PNG package to convert the image to grayscale values but I need help in creating the image with similar range of grayscle. Currently when I try to draw in Paint it ranges from 0:255, unlike in the training set which has negative values too.

Note: I do not know what format of image I need to use to get similar intensity values, my easiest way was to go to paint and draw the digit

The Problem:
[image: An Example of the Grayscale Values of the Digit 1]

```
im <- matrix(data=rev(X[567,]), nrow=20, ncol=20)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]          [,4]          [,5]          [,6]          [,7]          [,8]          [,9]         [,10]         [,11]         [,12]         [,13]
 [1,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
 [2,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  4.306236e-04 -4.538135e-03
 [3,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.0002343973 -1.140496e-02  2.497616e-02
 [4,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  1.084559e-04 -0.0017490639 -1.345621e-02  4.384232e-01
 [5,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  2.941176e-05 -4.375000e-04 -0.0261209150  2.488099e-01  9.544290e-01
 [6,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  2.393280e-04 -2.528663e-02  0.1323503711  8.318632e-01  1.015593e+00
 [7,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0001834414 -6.974929e-03  3.770381e-02  0.6445272331  1.033006e+00  8.613194e-01
 [8,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  2.445885e-05 -0.0001720764 -2.008902e-02  2.677583e-01  1.0012065346  9.811198e-01  3.359074e-01
 [9,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  3.487541e-04 -0.0256610004  1.337907e-01  8.190443e-01  1.0119159688  5.299348e-01 -2.273144e-03
[10,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0007352941 -1.754459e-02  0.0444801985  6.604204e-01  1.036383e+00  0.7427878881  6.253465e-02 -1.474359e-02
[11,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000 -0.0053142872  3.982375e-02  0.6389624523  1.033114e+00  8.733544e-01  0.1483327546 -1.978789e-02  5.014064e-04
[12,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0003370098 -0.0245936309  2.214513e-01  0.9496550623  1.001519e+00  4.032970e-01 -0.0262422045 -1.246885e-03  3.668827e-05
[13,]    0    0    0  2.201296e-05 -0.0071477926  0.0124218676  5.890595e-01  1.0428453590  7.664877e-01  6.238350e-02 -0.0170552566  1.654030e-04  0.000000e+00
[14,]    0    0    0 -1.326593e-04 -0.0214352533  0.1659780263  8.681923e-01  1.0228496087  4.833438e-01 -2.121145e-02 -0.0023410267  1.021242e-06  0.000000e+00
[15,]    0    0    0 -1.412275e-03 -0.0192939474  0.4265679126  1.037142e+00  0.9012997670  9.698972e-02 -1.290765e-02  0.0002604167  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
[16,]    0    0    0 -1.593035e-03 -0.0186662922  0.4575771889  1.093103e+00  0.7281629027 -3.015387e-02  7.327410e-04  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
[17,]    0    0    0 -3.634600e-04 -0.0099532952  0.1448730596  4.328676e-01  0.1434386592 -9.253983e-03  3.063725e-05  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
[18,]    0    0    0  4.647181e-05  0.0011291835 -0.0175039746 -5.072072e-02 -0.0191029196  1.039501e-03  1.043178e-17  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
[19,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
[20,]    0    0    0  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
              [,14]         [,15]         [,16]         [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
 [1,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
 [2,] -0.0216402846 -1.239362e-02  2.570125e-05  6.076389e-05     0     0     0
 [3,]  0.6271519370  6.741898e-01  1.490166e-02 -3.797542e-03     0     0     0
 [4,]  1.0680277608  5.460697e-01 -8.837061e-03 -2.389553e-03     0     0     0
 [5,]  0.8673059811  1.769967e-01 -1.832898e-02 -3.108660e-04     0     0     0
 [6,]  0.4489610566 -2.979454e-02 -2.363971e-03  5.238971e-05     0     0     0
 [7,]  0.0371314849 -7.122634e-03  2.040441e-04  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
 [8,] -0.0279941706  7.847214e-04  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
 [9,] -0.0058922249  1.244466e-17  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[10,]  0.0003111383  9.320045e-32  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[11,]  0.0000245098  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[12,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[13,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[14,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[15,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[16,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[17,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[18,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[19,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0
[20,]  0.0000000000  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00     0     0     0

image(1:20, 1:20, im, col=gray((0:255)/255)) #But My Lower Values Extend Past Help Required Here too to set the range (NOT 0:255)
```

[image: Using the Image Function to Plot]

I want to create (draw) certain digits myself and test, but I want to make sure they belong to the same range of values, how do I achieve that?

Comment: I am baffled that a PNG could go negative - maybe Glenn would be able to share his insights - @glennranders-pehrson.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am a novice when it comes to relating Images with Grayscale values. The values were actually provided as feature sets, they have negative values in them on which I trained. I want to test the model by writing digits myself but want to get the grayscale values of the same range (which is not happening when I use paint to draw a number)

Comment: Glenn helps out lots of folk on Stack Overflow and he co-wrote the PNG spec and coded it too, so I am hoping he would know the ins and outs of it....

Answer (score 1):

You want to scale the new data (from MSPaint) so it matches that of the data you used to train your model. Get the mean and variance of the training dataset and use `scale` to apply it to the new image.

```
means <- colMeans(training_data)
std <- apply(training_data, 2, FUN = sd, na.rm = T)
new_im <- scale(im, center = means, scale = std)
```

I would also suggest going back and creating a new model where the training data is properly scaled beforehand. Like @MarkSetchell I'm confused as to what negative values mean in PNGs.

Comment: Thanks Daisey for the perspective. Let me add some more context: each pixel is a feature and the grayscale the associated value. So if there are a 1000 training sets then for that pixel location I have thousand such values and I would require, if we are scaling across the 1000 training set for that pixel rather than within an image matrix

Comment: @AnuragH I'm not sure I understand your comment. Say each image in your training set is 256x256 pixels, then you would have 65,536 values for each image. Do you then mean you have 1000 such images? That's fine. Simply create a tidy matrix where each column represents a single pixel and each row represents a single image. That matrix will be 1000 x 65,536 which is large, but all the functions I suggested will handle okay.

Comment: I completely get what you suggested and you are absolutely right by the structure and that is how I have the data in the training set. I have +1 ed you :) I just wanted to add some more context. The problem is I have been provided with the data ranges as I have given in the example (like you say a prescaled data probably, I do not have the unscaled values to derive the mean and sd)

Comment: The assumption when scaling your new data to match your old data is your new data *looks like* your old data; the new data is a random draw from the same population as that of the old data. This is a large assumption. If you can instead scale each to an outside standard, perhaps 0:255 (or equivalent depending on how you converted to greyscale), you need not worry about this assumption. I'm not familiar with using `PNG` to convert to greyscale, but the code might give you a clue as to the "outside standard" to use.