# Understanding The Range In The Feature Set - Coursera ML EX4

Tags: image, pixel

I am referring here to the Coursera ML Course by Prof.Andrew NG, EX4 (Neural Network - Hand Written Digit Recognition).

The problem is in understanding how the ranges of Grayscale values were obtained which were provided in the problem, the range of values extend from negative to positive. For instance when for my feature set I try to check for the max and min it turns out to be 1.1277 and -0.13196 resp and all other values lie in between.

```
>> load('ex4data1.mat')
>> whos X
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        X        5000x400                 16000000  double

Total is 2000000 elements using 16000000 bytes

>> max(max(X))
ans =  1.1277
>> min(min(X))
ans = -0.13196
```

This is what the supporting exercise document says precisely about the feature set:

> > This is the same dataset that you used in the previous exercise. There are
> >     5000 training examples in ex3data1.mat, each training example is a 20 pixel by 20 pixel grayscale image of the digit. Each pixel is represented by a floating point number indicating the grayscale intensity at that location.

My Question Is: "Can some one please give me Step by Step the method of getting the grayscale pixel image intensity (i.e. Starting from the image itself, what were the actual pixel values, how were they rescaled (if they were), how do we arrive at the range as in the exercise? Wiki says the range of grayscale intensity is between 0 and 1"

More Details Here -  [Earlier Similar Question Asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644813/generating-grayscale-values-of-an-image)

Comment: I'im also interested